# Spec's for Eclipse and Android Studio

Tags: laptop, android

Hi I want to purchase a two in one laptop for college to bring around programming. I took a screenshot of the specs that it has. I googled and researched the specs needed for the IDEs Eclipse and Android Studio but I'm still a bit uneducated on the full extent of what I need. With the specs in the screen shot, would I be able to run the IDEs with moderate programming?!

**Relevant Specs:**

- OS: Windows 10
- CPU: Intel Core M 5Y10C (800MHz, 2 cores)
- GPU: Intel HD Graphics 5300
- RAM: 4GB
- Screen: 11.6" 1920x1080 IPS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would work fine for Eclipse and Android Studio. The only minor issue would be if you tried to run the Android emulator in Android Studio it might be slow since the computer only have 4GB of RAM. I would recommend at lease 6GB of RAM for better performance.